# Compiling a kivy based apk app using buildozer for android, requirement bcrypt returns error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I am new to this so please forgive my ignorance..

I am trying to compile a kivy based apk using buildozer following the steps in the kivy instructions and buildozer docs, I have edited the buildozer.spec file with my requirements.

My kivy app runs on my computer which is running python 3.12.1.

I am using an Ubuntu wsl on the same computer to compile the apk with buildozer which has python 3.10.12 on it (I wonder if this is whats confusing things)

My Ubuntu machine is using python 3.10.12, pip version 23.3.2, kivy version 2.3.0.

When I run the `buildozer -v android debug` command I keep getting the error:

```
  RAN: /home/charlie/androidapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v                                                                                                                                                                                     STDOUT:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE==========================                                                 If you are seeing an error here please try the following to                                                             successfully install bcrypt:                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most                                                  users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip                                                     =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE==========================                                                                                                                                                                 Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "/home/charlie/androidapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/bcrypt/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/bcrypt/setup.py", line 11, in <module>                                                                  from setuptools_rust import RustExtension                                                                           ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'
```

My buildozer.spec file is as follows:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Stingray SOS

# (str) Package name
package.name = stingraysos

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.stingraysos

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,csv

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png, media/,Plugins/

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = 

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, .venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
#version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python==3.10.12,kivy==2.3.0,bcrypt==4.1.2,mysql-connector-python==8.2.0,requests==2.31.0,setuptools==69.0.3
# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/media/watercolor-stingray-sea-animal-png.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/media/watercolor-stingray-sea-animal-png.png

# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3.12.1

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.3.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF
```

I have tried what is advised in the error and upgraded pip, I have tried directly installing setuptools_rust with pip and it says it is already satisfied.

I have managed to get an apk file out of buildozer by removing bcrypt from my requirements but the app does not run on my phone.

I have also tried to use python version 3.12.1 on my Ubuntu machine but Buildozer came back with a distutils error for bcrypt... even though bcrypt is working in my app which is using that version.

I have tried adding setuptools_rust to the requirments in my buildozer.spec file.

I am not sure if I am filling out the buildozer.spec file correctly. Any help greatly appreciated.

I feel like I am chasing my own tail a bit and hoped somebody might have some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Chaz,

In the sequence of your code provided above, is it important that the dir of  "source.dir = ." is in red? Also the "bin" in the last line is red:-

### (str) Source code where the main.py live

`source.dir = .`

### (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)

`source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,csv`

### (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching

`source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png, media/,Plugins/`

### (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)

`source.exclude_exts =`

### (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)

`source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, .venv`